# How to write this proof formally?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have to prove that if $V$ is an unitary vector space and $W,U$ are subspaces of $V$, then $W^\bot \cap U^\bot=(W\land U)^\bot$ where $\bot$ means orthogonal complement and  $\land$ is conjunction of vector spaces, $W\land U=\langle W\cup U\rangle$. Let $W_b=(w_1,w_2,...,w_n), U_b=(u_1,u_2, ...,u_n)$ be the bases of $W$ and $U$. Then finding $(W\land U)^\bot$ means solving homogene equations equal to solving a matrice of  $\begin{pmatrix} 
w_1 | 0\\ 
w_2|0\\
...\\
w_n|0\\
u_1|0\\
...\\
u_n|0
        \end{pmatrix}$
To find a solution to $W^\bot \cap U^\bot$ we need to find the orthogonal complement for $W$ and $U$ simmilarly as before, and then find vectors that are in $U$ and in $W$ in the same time. The solution of this task is to find a solution to matrix above. Since the two tasks have equal solution, the equation is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, avoid the use of bases. This should be repeated: If possible, avoid the use of bases. This is not only because you may be lucky to prove a slightly more general result, but also the proof will usually look better if all those indices and sums are gone, and finally the base-less proof may give you more insight.

So here we go:

Assume $v\in W^\perp\cap U^\perp$.
Let $x\in W\wedge U$ be arbitrary. Then we can write $x=w+u$ with $w\in W$, $u\in U$.
Then $$\langle v,x\rangle=\langle v, w\rangle+\langle v,u\rangle = 0+0=0,$$
i.e. $v\in(U\wedge W)^\perp$. This shows $W^\perp\cap U^\perp\subseteq (U\wedge W)^\perp$.

Now assume $x\in(U\wedge W)^\perp$. Let $u\in U$ be arbitrary.
Then $u=u+0\in U\wedge W$, hence $\langle x,u\rangle=0$ and thus $x\in U^\perp$.
Similarly, $x\in W^\perp$, i.e. $x\in U^\perp\cap W^\perp$.
This shows  $(U\wedge W)^\perp\subseteq W^\perp\cap U^\perp$.

In summary, $(U\wedge W)^\perp= W^\perp\cap U^\perp$.

If there is one thing you learned from this problem, I hope it is this:
If possible, avoid the use of bases.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.